# How to get "totalPrice" from GooglePay checkout response

Tags: api, response, payment, checkout, google-pay

I must get **total price** from GooglePay checkout response, but google provide only responses like that:

```
{
  "paymentRequest": {
    "apiVersionMinor": 0,
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "paymentMethodData": {
      "description": "Mastercard ??????0657",
      "tokenizationData": {
        "type": "PAYMENT_GATEWAY",
        "token": "examplePaymentMethodToken"
      },
      "type": "CARD",
      "info": {
        "cardNetwork": "MASTERCARD",
        "cardDetails": "0657"
      }
    },
    "email": "gaskevich06@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: You generally supply the total price as part of the request. Is there any reason why you can't use the value supplied in the request?

Comment: I think it is not safe to get a request about payments and confirmations directly from frontend.
The comparison of how many human pays and how many I got isn't optimized. It has many bugs and vulnerabilities. sure I can use JWT to secure the data, but... I think there is an easier method to do that

Comment: You're right about not trusting the front end, but relying on the response is also trusting the front end. Note that Google Pay doesn't actually execute the payment, it only returns a payment credential that you can use to process the payment on the back-end. The total price that you supply in the front-end is only used to show the user how much the transaction is for. The actual amount processed depends on what you send to your payment processor.

Comment: So I can get the payment data from payment processor (for example: Stripe) transaction, right?

Comment: You will need to refer to their documentation.